# Remove multiple content in XAML string

Tags: regex, windows-8, richtextblock

Hi I have a xaml string like this:

```
<InlineUIContainer>
  <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource Link}" NavigateUri="someuri">
    <Span>
      <InlineUIContainer>
        <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource Link}" NavigateUri="someuri">SOME TEXT</HyperlinkButton> 
      </InlineUIContainer>
    </Span>
    some undesirable text!
  </HyperlinkButton>
</InlineUIContainer>
```

I need to convert this xaml to a RichTextBlock content but I have no control of the string generation I only receive the string, so as you can see in the fragment I need to remove the undesirable text because an HyperLinkButton can't have two contents.

So I need one of two things:

1. Remove the outter HyperLinkButton that is not necessary or
2. Remove the undesirable text in the sample

Could someone help me with the Regex or something to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although probably not the best solution, as a regex can be easily tripped up by many edge cases. This expression will find the undesireable text and replace it

Regex: `(<\/Span>[\s\r\n]*)(^.*[\r\n]*)(?=\s*<\/HyperlinkButton>[\s\r\n]*<\/InlineUIContainer>)`

Replace with: `$1`

[image]

## Example

Live working example: http://regexr.com?35efl

**Sample Text**

```
<InlineUIContainer>
  <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource Link}" NavigateUri="someuri">
    <Span>
      <InlineUIContainer>
        <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource Link}" NavigateUri="someuri">SOME TEXT</HyperlinkButton> 
      </InlineUIContainer>
    </Span>
    some undesirable text!
    with multiple 
    lines
  </HyperlinkButton>
</InlineUIContainer>
```

**After Replacement**

```
<InlineUIContainer>
  <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource Link}" NavigateUri="someuri">
    <Span>
      <InlineUIContainer>
        <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource Link}" NavigateUri="someuri">SOME TEXT</HyperlinkButton> 
      </InlineUIContainer>
    </Span>
  </HyperlinkButton>
</InlineUIContainer>
```

Comment: Hi thanks but it doesn't seem to remove it :( also \s is not a valid escape sequence :(

Comment: Since this is on a Windows platform, are you using a .net regex engine? And are you using the `S` option which triggers a `.` to also match new line characters?